# jQuery AJAX retrieve SVG from file - ERROR: 'not well-formed'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, svg

I have been using many different svg from inkscape and using .load to a specific container element for a while. I recently tried changing the load to a get (AJAX), mainly to be able to prepend the svg.

This worked pefectly, svg prepended to element as should do, problem is I get the console error 'not well-formed' when using the ajax get method of retrieving the svg file. I dont like ignoring errors, but this does interfere with the page content.

Didnt think it was an issue with the svg, because it was working previoulsy, just to make sure I checked the required namespaces in svg where included(although using inkscape default metadata from standard save). eg:

```
<svg      
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
```

**Original load Method (No Error):**

```
$('.container-svg').load("img/floorplan/"+ source +".svg", null, function() 
{
   //other things happen
});
```

**New Ajax Method (Error):**

```
$.get("img/floorplan/"+ source +".svg").done(function( data )
{
    $(".container-svg").prepend($(data).find("svg"));
    //other things happen
});
```

- Is this related to the metadata in the svg file?
- should/how do I correct the error?

Comment: `$.get()` expecting `html` at response ? Tried setting `dataType` to `"svg"` ?

Comment: **@guest271314** Thanks hadn't thought of setting datatype, svg does need html .....btw svg is not a valid format.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out....
$.get() is a shorthand version for $.ajax(), except i think it uses XML as default datatype. I thought it would use HTML as default so just used longhand and assigned dataType : 'html' this is now compatible with svg.

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "img/floorplan/"+ source +".svg" ,
    dataType: 'html',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) 
    {         
        $(".container-svg").prepend(data);
    }
});
```